# DynamoDB: scan() with FilterExpression that combines multiple attributes

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

Items in my DynamoDB table have the following format:

```
{
  'id': 1,
  'last_check': 1234556,
  'check_interval': 100,
  ....
}
```

Now I'd like to scan the table and find all items where `last_check + check_interval` is less than some given value `last_check_time`. I did not find a way to create a FilterExpression that combines two attributes so I'm currently doing it the following way:

```
last_check_time = time.time()
response = status_table.scan(
    ProjectionExpression='id, last_check, check_interval',
    FilterExpression = Attr('last_check').lt(last_check_time)
)
# manually filter the items and only preserve those with last_check + check_interval < last_check_time:
for item in response['Items']:
    if item['last_check'] + item['check_interval'] < last_check_time:
        # This is one of the items I'm interested in!
        ....
    else:
        # Not interested in this item. And I'd prefer to let DynamoDB filter this out.
        continue
```

Is there a way to let DynamoDB do the filtering and therefore make the for loop in the example above obsolete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it is currently not possible to request DynamoDB to perform a filtered calculation for you, but you could create another attribute which is the sum of the two attributes, and you have a couple of approaches to achieve that;

1. Potentially compute an additional attribute (last_check + check_interval) in code when writing the item to DynamoDB.
2. Use DynamoDB Triggers to create an additional attribute (last_check + check_interval)

You can use either option to create a new attribute on the item to filter on.

Comment: Thank! I guess I'll go with approach 1 then.